# Inject XML data into HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css, xml

I'm currently in the process of trying to inject an XML file into my HTML and then to show it in a table. I'll show a small part of the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product top-level-category="DSLR" sub-level-category="Camera Bundles">
    <id>0001</id>
    <title>NIKON D3300 DSLR Camera with 18-55 mm f/3.5-5.6 II ED Zoom Lens – BlacK</title>
    <brand>Nikon</brand>
    <price>279.00</price>
    <description>The Nikon D3300 DSLR Camera with 18-55 mm f/3.5-5.6 II ED Zoom Lens allows you to capture special moments in glorious high quality. Unforgettable memories, unforgettable photos. Small and lightweight, the D3300 has a 24.2 megapixel, 23.5 x 15.6 mm CMOS sensor with remarkable light sensitivity that produces amazingly sharp images. It performs well in low light with an ISO range of 100 to 12800 (extendable to 25600). Your images will be packed with fine textures and natural colours to really capture the atmosphere of whichever situation you find yourself in. Capture clear, colourful photographs in all manner of lighting conditions as the camera's EXPEED 4 image processor goes to work, delivering gorgeous photos every time.</description>
</product>
```

Taking into account the tags ID, title, brand, price and description I'd begun trying to write up a piece of jQuery (to follow) to try and link it to the table, but I've come to a standstill as it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "productsXmlStructure.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
      $('#t01').append('<th>ID</th>'); 
      $('#t01').append('<table id="show_table">'); 
      $(xml).find('show').each(function(){
        var $show = $(this);
        var id = $show.find('ID').text();
        var title = $show.find('Title').text();
        var brand = $show.find('Brand').text();
        var price = $show.find('Price').text();
        var desc = $show.find('Description').text();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I don't have a lot of knowledge surrounding the language, however my table is below. Not entirely sure where I've gone wrong here so any help would be appreciated.

```
<table id="t01" table border="2" style="width:75%" table align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('#t01').append('<th>ID</th>'); $('#t01').append('<table id="show_table">');` doesn't make sense. Nowhere in HTML may a table element be a sibling of a th element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `filter` instead of `find`
2. `product` instead of `show` (according the XML)
3. For each `product` append row to `#t01`.
4. For each property append cell to the above row with the data.

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <product top-level-category="DSLR" sub-level-category="Camera Bundles"> <id>0001</id> <title>NIKON D3300 DSLR Camera with 18-55 mm f/3.5-5.6 II ED Zoom Lens – BlacK</title> <brand>Nikon</brand> <price>279.00</price> <description>The Nikon D3300 DSLR Camera with 18-55 mm f/3.5-5.6 II ED Zoom Lens allows you to capture special moments in glorious high quality. Unforgettable memories, unforgettable photos. Small and lightweight, the D3300 has a 24.2 megapixel, 23.5 x 15.6 mm CMOS sensor with remarkable light sensitivity that produces amazingly sharp images. It performs well in low light with an ISO range of 100 to 12800 (extendable to 25600). Your images will be packed with fine textures and natural colours to really capture the atmosphere of whichever situation you find yourself in. Capture clear, colourful photographs in all manner of lighting conditions as the camera\'s EXPEED 4 image processor goes to work, delivering gorgeous photos every time.</description></product>';

$(xml).filter('product').each(function(){
  var $show = $(this);
  var data = {
    id: $show.find('ID').text(),
    title: $show.find('Title').text(),
    brand: $show.find('Brand').text(),
    price: $show.find('Price').text(),
    desc: $show.find('Description').text()
  };

  var row = $('<tr />');
  for (var prop in data) {
    $('<td>' + data[prop] + '</td>').appendTo(row);  
  }
  
  $('#t01').append(row);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t01" table border="2" style="width:75%" table align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Will try and work this into my code and let you know! Looks great though, thank-you!